# If limit $x$ approaches $2$ of $f(x)=5$, then how is it possible that $f(2)$ can be equal to $3$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> According to my maths book, it states that while the limit as $x$ approaches $2$ can be equal to $5$, it is also possible that $f(2)=3$. This is mind boggling for me and I would like some graphical representation of this actually happening

The book had stated the following:

"the graph could have a hole at $(2, 5)$ and be defined such that $f(2) = 3.$"

In my graphing paper, I have drawn myself a dot at $(2,5)$ with a hole, but there cannot be $(2,3)$ on the graph, or can there be?

Comment: The limit and the actual **function value** at a point $a$ aren't always the same. They are the same when the function $f$ is **continuous** at $a$, because by definition, $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)$. When $f$ is **not** continuous at $a$, its limit can be different (e.g. imagine the line $y=x$ and put an open circle (this is called a discontinuity)at $(1,1)$.  fill in a dark circle at $(1,2)$. If we **define** a function $f$ to be this, then it is obvious that the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ does not approach $f(1) = 2$, as the limit is $1$.

Comment: (the function defined above is just the line $y=x$ for all $x\neq 1$, and when $x=1$, the function value is defined to be $2$.

Comment: "I have drawn myself a dot at (2,5) with a hole, but there cannot be (2,3) on the graph, or can there be?" Yes, there can be a dot at $(2,3)$ and a hole at $(2,5)$. This will not be a continuous function but it is indeed a function.

Answer (score 4):

The picture below is my attempt to visually represent such a function for you. I apologise for my poor free-hand drawing, but the hole in the line should be at the point $(2, 5)$, and then the dot below it is the point $(2, 3)$.

The limit of $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 2$ is clearly 5, because if you imagine following the function from either side as you get closer to $x = 2$, you get closer and closer to a $y$ value of 5 - which is what the limit is. In fact, by making $x$ arbitrarily close to $2$, you can get $y$ arbitrarily close to 5.

However, $f(2) = 3$, so if you try to go directly to the function's value at that point rather than approaching the limit, you get a completely different value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example. let $f $ be the function defined by

$f (x)=-x+7$ if $x\ne 2$ and $f (2)=3$.

then

$\lim_{x\to 2,x\ne 2}f (x )=-2+7=5$.

in this case, we say that $f $ is not continuous ( there is a hole) at the point $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Find the limit of $f(x) = (x-1)/(x-1)$ as $x$ goes to 1. See that the limit you find has nothing to do with the fact that $f$ is undefined at 1.

Now, in a piece wise manner, choose $f$ to be any value you want at $x$ = 1. The limit stays unchanged.

Limits are concerned with local behavior near a point, but not necessarily what is happening *at* that point.

Answer (score 0):

A limit can be conceptualized as the value the function "approximates" when you put in inputs that are very close -- "arbitrarily close" meaning as close as you desire -- to the place at which you are taking the limit. That doesn't, however, mean the function must *equal* that value at that point, only that there is some value, call it $L$, that *were* the function to take it on at that point, it would be approximable to any desired precision by simply taking an input suitably close to that point. That is essentially what the formal definition says: given some approximation precision $\epsilon$, by choosing $x$ suitably close to the point of limit taking, call it $c$, we can make the distance or *error* $d(f(x), L)$ between the function value and the approximated value $L$ to be within that tolerance, i.e. $d(f(x), L) < \epsilon$. A limit exists if such an $L$ exists, that is, the function approximates in this fashion. Another way to think of it is that a limit value is the value you would have to redefine the function to equal at that point in order to make it continuous at that point if it is not already so. (This is where I disagree with the usual introduction of limits and continuity: I would suggest to start with continuity first, then go to limits. The gist of continuity is really the "calculator property" that you can get an approximate value of the function at any desired point even without knowing that desired point's value exactly, as long as you know it well *enough* . Which is why a calculator can do things like square roots and trig and still produce useful answers, even when you don't know the angles exactly.)

Thus we can see how it could be different: the function could approximate that $L$ for values of $x$ arbitrarily close to the point $c$, but not *AT* $c$ exactly. Thus a function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
5 - (x - 2),\ \mbox{if}\ x \ne 2\\
3,\ \mbox{if}\ x = 2
\end{cases}$$

approximates $5$ arbitrarily well if we just choose $x$ really close to 2 (since the $5 - (x - 2)$ bit subtracts as small an amount from 5 as how close we are to 2 (up to sign)), but *at* 2, the function equals 3, by definition. If I plug $f(2.00000000001)$ I get the value $4.99999999999$ (exactly!) which is super close to 5, but if I plug $f(3)$ I get $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Because from definition: 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L \iff \{\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : 0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|< \epsilon\}
$$
you don't need $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) $

Comment: for the limit to exist

Comment: meaning you can give whatever value you want to $f(x_0)$

Comment: even further the definition doesnt rely on $f(x_0)$ so it can be given any value.

Answer (score 0):

It happens only when the function is discontinuous at a point $x_0$, because for the continuous function the left and right limits are equal to the value of the function at the point $x_0$: $$\lim_\limits{x\to x_0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to x_0^{+}}f(x)=f(x_0).$$

For example, consider the piece-wise function: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ \ \ x+3,& x<2 \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ 3, &x=2 \\ -x+6, &x> 2\end{cases}$$
The graph of the function is:

[image]

Note:
$$\begin{align} 
\lim_\limits{x\to 2^{-}}f(x) & = \lim_\limits{x\to 2^{-}}(x+3)=5. \\
\lim_\limits{x\to 2^{+}}f(x) & = \lim_\limits{x\to 2^{+}}(-x+6)=4. \\
f(2) & = 3.
\end{align}$$